# Скрипт без таймаута

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Бывают скрипты, которые должны выполнять свою работу часа 4-6. Но в таком случаи вылетает таймаут, и скрипт не завершает свою работу. Очень интересно узнать как можно сделать такой скрипт без таймаута? Да, и как делают прогресс бар?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set_time_limit если я правильно понял, но вот никогда не видел скриптов, которые выполняются 4 часа)

По прогресс-барам очень много информации, возможно вы имели ввиду прогресс загрузки файла, тогда [вот ссылка](http://adobkin.com/?p=767) (PHP 5.4+), но можно еще найти варианты)

Comment: Спасибо за полезную информацию